# Is it better to create a variable than have a huge line of code?

Tags: java, android, coding-style

I'm not sure how to phrase this, so looking it up was quite difficult and showed up nothing. I'm currently learning to program at university and I have a question about what I guess is programming standards. I've been doing some Android stuff and have a couple of areas where examples are showing variables that I don't deem necessary so I want to know which of the following is more acceptable, or if it's purely preference.

**Example 1**

```
((TextView)view.findViewById(views[i])).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

**Example 2**

```
TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(views[i]);
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I'm currently operating on the theory that if I'm using it once I should follow `Example 1` and if I use something more than once I follow `Example 2`. This is a personal preference though.

Is there a specific standard when it comes to this? I noticed that some lines (example below) can get quite long and I had a tutor who used to complain about that, so I figured it'd be worth following up.

**Example 3**

```
(menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, R.string.oauth).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_oauth)).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

I'm sure you get what I'm trying to say! Currently it's not a huge issue because I'm the only person who sees most of my code, but I figure it's best to get into the right habits before I start working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "huge line of code" == **bad**, very bad. Strive for *readability*, not *conciseness*, unless with conciseness you improve readability. Think of your audience including others who review or maintain this code, and even more importantly *your **future** self*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for readability. Reread your code, and think of somebody else (probably yourself a few years down the road) trying to figure out what you programmed.

If you program right you only need comments on *what* you are trying to achieve and possibly a few lines about strategy. Never go for multiple statements on one line if it can be easily avoided. Use legible variable names that capture the meaning of the variables and let the IDE help you with filling them in. Don't care too much about optimization; try to get it right instead. You will never notice those extra variables.

Finally, try to play with styles and look back at them over a month. You will quickly find that you hate overcrowded lines. After a while you should be ready to set the style within your IDE (and/or checkstyle).

Coding is more about maintainability than speed of typing.

Answer (score 2):

"huge line of code" == bad code, very bad code. You should always strive for *readability*, not *conciseness*, unless with conciseness you improve readability.

When coding, think of your audience including others who must review or maintain your code, and even more importantly think of your ***future self*** for when you yourself must review and maintain your code down the road.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it matters too much, the local variable will be released once you leave the enclosing block/method anyway. It really bils down to coding style, at which point I tend towards more legible code than trying to optimize the number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Long lines are generally bad.  I know it makes you feel clever to put ten lines of code into one glorious line, but the compiler/interpreter doesn't care.  I'll tell you who does care.  People who have to read your code, and they're not going to like it.  Use variables.  Lines like that would fall out of code during refactoring because they make code maintenance nearly impossible.  A few well named variables will make your code a hundred times more readable, and 0% less efficient.